# How can I create a .deb file that adds a repository to sources.list.d?

Tags: ppa, repository, packaging, deb

I want to start sharing .deb files that automatically add new repos to an Ubuntu installation (like the ones present in puppetlabs.com).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a postinst script to your package:

> Broadly speaking the `preinst` [script] is called before (a particular version of) a package is unpacked, and the `postinst` afterwards... The `postinst` should still attempt any actions for which its dependencies are required, since they will normally be available, but consider the correct error handling approach if those actions fail.

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html

**An example**

The Opera browser is adding itself to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list with the postinst script: http://pastebin.com/u6SR6krY

Comment: I think it's maybe a little too much for my current knowledge. But thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: @user26687 The complete packaging guide does not exist.